# Is there a penalty for skipping cutscenes?

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

I know in FFX-2, if you choose to skip a cutscene, it'll prevent you from getting a maximum completion percentage (100%). Is there anything like that in Lightning Returns if you skip a cutscene?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware

I have already completed the game twice, and in the secod run I skipped the cutscenes

I also already have the platinum, so it's unlikely to happen